# Можно ли НЕ подключать стили родительской темы wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Другая формулировка вопроса: если стили родительской темы - рудимент?

Новичкам при работе с wordpress рекомендуется не создовать свои темы, а создавать дочерние из уже имеющихся. Так я и поступил. ВО всех руководствах по созданию дочерних рассказываются разные варианты подключения стилей. Я так понимаю, что эти руководства ориентированы на тех, кто css не понимает. У меня же какой-никакой, но опыт фронтенд разработки есть.

В моём файле стилей всё настроено близко к идеалу. Стилей много у меня, поэтому заниматься тем, чтобы перебивать стили родительской темы, желания нету. Лишние стили в head я деактивировал, если что.

Ещё раз вопрос: могу ли я НЕ подключать стили для дочерней темы? С точки зрения технической, СЕО или ещё чего-то - это ведь не будет нарушением?

Насколько я понимаю, то могу отказаться подключать стили. Я так и намерен поступить. Но мне нужно подтверждение от опытных, от сообщества.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> могу ли я НЕ подключать стили для дочерней темы?

Стили можно не прописывать, но файл стилей - единственный обязательный файл для темы.
Матчасть:
https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.90.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B

https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B#.D0.9D.D0.B5.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BC.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BB_style.css

Файл стилей родительской темы подключать не обязательно.